# Windows 8 mouse control

Tags: autohotkey

I have an autohotkey script that resets the cursor position to the center of the screen on a key press (windows 7) but in windows 8, that function does not work. Is there a change that I need to make to the script in order to make it function properly?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, run AHK with admin rights (right click on icon when you start ahk and select run as...)

Comment: That did not solve the issue, sadly. Compatibility mode is scratch as well.

Comment: Did you try changing `Run this program as an administrator` on the AutoHotkey.exe as well? (Properties -> Compatibility tab). That little checkbox solved all sorts of issues when I moved to Win 8.